# Adding a className using variables (HTML, ReactJS)

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have the following div -

```
 <div className={classes}>
```

`classes` is some variable that has some string value.

```
const classes = 'constant-className'
```

i want to add the string `'added-classNamme'` after the current className so that the final className becomes:

```
 'constant-className added-classNamme'
```

How can this be achieved??

I tried with `<div className={classes + 'added-classNamme'}>` but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like:

```
<div className={`${classes} added-classname`}>
```

Refer [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).